# Increase time by every second in Bash

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I have a requirement to increase the time by every second from the past 5 mins time and do some execution on the formed time.

I was able to get the past 5 mins time and save it in a variable using the -v command of date since I am working on MacOS

```
prevdate=$(date -v -5M)
```

Now I am trying to increasing this time by every second. I have tried to use echo command to check if the output is correct but I always end with failure as command not found. I tried the below command.

```
echo "$prevdate -v +1S"
```

Also tried to convert the prevdate to epoch second but could not do it.

```
echo "$prevdate +%s"
```

How can I use a varibale with a date command in echo command. Pls help.

Comment: Note that bash has a `SECONDS` variable that, whenever checked, will always give you the number of seconds since the script was started. Generally, you shouldn't need to manually increment anything at all.

Comment: `prevdate=date -v -5M` should produce `-v: command not found` if this is bash. If that's what you mean by `but I always with failure as command not found` then you should include the error message in the question to help people understand your issue.

Comment: @tjm3772 I am not getting error for storing datetime to prevdate. I am using the correct command. Sorry, I typed incorrectly here, corrected it now. But I am facing the issue to execute the date options with the store variable prevdate. If I do ```echo "$prevdate +%s"``` it shows ```Sun May 14 14:11:59 IST 2023 +%s``` instead of showing epoch seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You're better of keeping the Epoch time in a variable, the integer is way easier to do math on.

For example:

1. Start by getting the current epoch
2. Increment the epoch time when needed
3. Convert to human-readable if needed

---

Demo script, that loops 5 times, for each second, it logs the current time:

<sub>**Note**: MacOs based `date` commands!</sub>

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Now + Minus 5 minutes
t=$(date +%s)
minus_5=$(($t - 300))

# Log staring values
echo "Now : $t ($(date -r $t))"
echo "-5m : $minus_5 ($(date -r $minus_5))"
echo ''

# Example Loop
debugLoop=0
while [[ $((debugLoop++)) -lt 5 ]]; do

    # Increment
    t=$((t + 1))

    # Log
    echo "Loop: $t ($(date -r $t))"

    # Delay
    sleep 1
done
```

This output the following (as of now)

```
Now : 1678814087 (Tue Mar 14 18:14:47 CET 2023)
-5m : 1678813787 (Tue Mar 14 18:09:47 CET 2023)

Loop: 1678814088 (Tue Mar 14 18:14:48 CET 2023)
Loop: 1678814089 (Tue Mar 14 18:14:49 CET 2023)
Loop: 1678814090 (Tue Mar 14 18:14:50 CET 2023)
Loop: 1678814091 (Tue Mar 14 18:14:51 CET 2023)
Loop: 1678814092 (Tue Mar 14 18:14:52 CET 2023)
```

Comment: Assuming the OP is using a modern bash release, instead of `t=$(date +%s)`, I'd suggest `printf -v t '%(%s)T' -1`; much lower overhead. And you can convert an epoch time value to a human form with the same construct, passing the epoch time in place of -1 and the format you actually want in place of `%s`. That way you also don't need to distinguish between MacOS/BSD and GNU versions of the `time` command (again, assuming a modern bash... which, on MacOS, would need to come from Nix/MacPorts/Homebrew/etc, as Apple doesn't ship one)

Comment: Yea, totally agree, but since OP only mentioned MacOS I use bash3.2 valid syntax. Thanks for your comment.